# SQL Doesnt Want to match strings with spaces for some reason

Tags: sql

I have this SQL Query that is not comparing properly so I commented it out the WHERE clause.    When returning the AF.ActivityNote it always has 2 spaces after it no matter if I do RTRIM on it or not. I think those spaces are the issue that wont let the commented WHERE clause to properly match the string against userfield33.

```
  SELECT CAST(UF.UserField33 AS NVARCHAR) , RTRIM(CAST(AF.ActivityNote AS NVARCHAR))
        FROM [BCMTEST01].[dbo].[ActivityContacts] as AC INNER JOIN [BCMTEST01].[dbo].[ActivityFullView] as AF
            ON AC.ActivityID = AF.ActivityID INNER JOIN [BCMTEST01].[dbo].[OpportunityExportView] as OP
            ON AC.ContactID = OP.ContactServiceID INNER JOIN [BCMTEST01].[dbo].[UserFields] as UF
            ON OP.ContactServiceID = UF.ContactServiceID
            WHERE ContactID = 8376
        --WHERE  RTRIM(CAST(UF.UserField33 AS NVARCHAR) = RTRIM(CAST(AF.ActivityNote AS NVARCHAR))
        ORDER BY ContactID ASC
```

Comment: Are you sure the sting has spaces? If they're not being removed by RTRIM(), it is likely that they're really some other ("unprintable") characters. Try some function that shows the string in hex, or check it in a debugger, to make certain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should *always* include the length when converting to `nvarchar`, `varchar`, `char`, and `nchar`.  So use something like:

```
cast(uf.userfield33 as nvarchar(255)) -- or whatever length you like, so long as you have something
```

The last two characters are not spaces.  Do something like:

```
select ascii(right( AF.ActivityNote, 1))
```

To see what the character value is.  You can then use `replace` to get rid of it.  Or, you can just chop off the last two characters (if that works for your application).

By the way, I am assuming you are using SQL Server based on the syntax of the query.

Here is an alternative `where` clause:

```
where (case when right(AF.ActivityNote, 2) = char(10)+CHar(13)
            then LEFT(AF.ActivityNote, LEN(AF.ActivityNote) - 2)
            else AF.ActivityNote
       end) = CAST(UF.UserField33 AS NVARCHAR(255)
```

I'm not a big fan of `case` statements in `where` clauses.  I would actually put the logic in a subquery.  Also, I might have the order of the 10/13 backwards.

Comment: Yes sql is on server. ASCII returned value of 10. I cannot do replace, since it will replace all instances of ASCII10 but how would i replace only trailing ones?

Comment: @PaShKa . . . Are they both ASCII 10 or is one ASCII 10 and the other ASCII 13?  (Good ole ASCII carriage return/line feed.)

Comment: Gordon it worked, just need to switch char(10) and char(13) places.. its char(13) + char(10)